# Alfresco custom data list layout

Tags: layout, alfresco, datalist, alfresco-share

I have created a custom data list in Alfresco, and have populated its model with the desired data columns. However, when I view the list in Alfresco share, the order is completely off, and there are elements that I have not defined in the model.

I have searched extensively as to how to fix this, and have not been successful. From what I understand, I need to define the layout in the share-config-custom.xml, which I have attempted below (snippet of only what I added):

```html
  <config evaluator="model-type" condition="orpdl:orpList">
  <forms>
   <form>
    <field-visibility>
     <show id="orpdl:programName" />
    </field-visibility>
    <create-form template="../data-lists/forms/dataitem.ftl" />
    <appearance>
     <field id="orpdl:programName">
                       <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl" />
     </field>
               </appearance>
   </form>
  </forms>
 </config>
 
 <config evaluator="node-type" condition="orpdl:orpList">
  <forms>
   <form>
    <field-visibility>
     <show id="orpdl:programName" />
    </field-visibility>
    <create-form template="../data-lists/forms/dataitem.ftl" />
    <appearance>
     <field id="orpdl:programName">
                       <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl" />
     </field>
               </appearance>
   </form>
  </forms>
 </config>
```

Content model:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Definition of new Model -->
<model name="orpdl:orpDataListModel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">

 <!-- Optional meta-data about the model -->
 <description>Information retrieved from the Opportunity Registration Process workflow form.</description>
 <author>Alan George</author>
 <version>1.0</version>

 <!-- Imports are required to allow references to definitions in other models -->
 <imports>
  <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
  <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d" />
  <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
  <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm" />
  <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0" prefix="sys" />
  <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0" prefix="dl" />
 </imports>

 <!-- Introduction of new namespaces defined by this model -->
 <namespaces>
  <namespace uri="http://www.test.com/model/orpDataListModel/1.0" prefix="orpdl" />
 </namespaces>
 
 <constraints>
        <constraint name="orpdl:contractTypeList" type="LIST">
   <parameter name="allowedValues">
    <list>
            <value>T&amp;M</value>
            <value>FFP</value>
            <value>CPFF</value>
            <value>CPIF</value>
    </list>
         </parameter>
  </constraint>
 </constraints>
 
 <types>
  <type name="orpdl:orpList">
   <title>Opportunity Registration Process</title>
   <description>Information retrieved from the Opportunity Registration Process workflow form.</description>
   <parent>dl:dataListItem</parent>
   <properties>
    <property name="orpdl:programName">
     <title>Program Name</title>
     <type>d:text</type>
     <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </property>
    <property name="orpdl:programDescription">
     <title>Program Description</title>
     <type>d:text</type>
     <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </property>
    <property name="orpdl:client">
     <title>Client</title>
     <type>d:text</type>
     <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </property>
    <property name="orpdl:contractType">
     <title>Contract Type</title>
     <type>d:text</type>
     <mandatory>true</mandatory>
     <constraints>
      <constraint ref="orpdl:contractTypeList" />
     </constraints>
    </property>
    <property name="orpdl:value">
     <title>Value</title>
     <type>d:text</type>
     <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </property>
   </properties>
  </type>
 </types>
</model>
```

The goal of this code is to have only the programName text box appear. But this is what I'm seeing:

[image: Datalist]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add content model(Where you have defined datalist) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are entering wrong condition in `<config>` tag.
Below

`<config evaluator="model-type" condition="orpdl:orpDataListModel">` 
                      
should replace with 
`<config evaluator="model-type" condition="orpdl:issuesList">`

This will also apply to `node-type`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, that was just a typo on my end. I updated the example code to reflect my current code, with the type and config names being updated to "orpList". I'm still seeing unwanted elements in my data list.

Comment: Please see the image.I have deployed code which is in http://pastebin.com/LVWhLEBd link

Comment: Does the service-context.xml file not belong in /alfresco/module/<project>/context? Otherwise my code is exactly the same as yours, and I'm still not seeing what you're seeing. I upvoted you for your efforts.

Comment: can you upload your all file somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79781/discussion-between-krutik-jayswal-and-alan-george).